# Constraint Layout for different screen sizes

Tags: android, user-interface, screen-size, android-constraintlayout

how to auto adjust gap or margins between two widgets for different screen sizes like ios using Constraint layout.Different screens sizes can be 4.7,5.0 or 5.5. All these devices select dimen from dimens-normal so is there any another way to auto adjust margin between two widgets

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="dummy"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/lion"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abc" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xyz" />
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_et_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/et_email_hint" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_et_email">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/et_password_hint" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/bt_sign_in"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/til_password"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/til_password"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_password"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="403dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_forgot_password"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="41sp"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="17sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/tv_forgot_password"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
```

In the above part i am setting margin values as hard coded. So if i run the code on 5.0 screen size it is fine. But if i run it on 5.5 screen size then instead of adjusting the margin it leaves blank space at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Use Guideline constraint to provide percentage to your view according to different screen size.

```
 <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.09" />
```

Refer following google link.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Comment: This class has been deprecated.